# Unpivot N columns into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that holds all folder's id and their corresponding parent id.

I want to export all parent folders of a folder, but I need these folders to just be in one column.

I am trying to use a pivot table for this but it will not work for some reason. All pivot examples online contain aggregative functions. Do I have to implement one in as well for this to work? I don't think I do.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT F.Id, F1.Id, F2.Id, F3.Id, F4.Id, F5.Id, F5.ParentId
FROM Folder F 
    LEFT JOIN Folder F1 ON F1.Id = F.ParentId
    LEFT JOIN Folder F2 ON F2.Id = F1.ParentId
    LEFT JOIN Folder F3 ON F3.Id = F2.ParentId
    LEFT JOIN Folder F4 ON F4.Id = F3.ParentId
    LEFT JOIN Folder F5 ON F5.Id = F4.ParentId
WHERE F.Id = '65D33613-9476-4BC8-90AA-2DA622CAA7CD') AS Folders
UNPIVOT(
Idens FOR F.Id IN (Id)
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You can use an aggregate, when needed, that will return the same value as when the data is not grouped. AVG(Fx.ID) in the query above will yield the same value of Fx.ID used in the join predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive common table expression instead of `UNPIVOT`.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, 1 RN FROM Folder WHERE Id = '65D33613-9476-4BC8-90AA-2DA622CAA7CD'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT F.Id,  F.ParentID, RN+1 RN FROM Folder F INNER JOIN CTE ON F.Id = CTE.ParentID
)
SELECT 'Id_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,RN) Idens ,  Id FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 'ParentId' Idens , Id FROM CTE ORDER BY RN DESC) AS Parent
```